# SQL Server : take 1 to many record set and make 1 record per id

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need some help. I need to take the data from these 3 tables and create an output that looks like below. The `plan_name_x` and `pending_tallyx` columns are derived to make one line per claim id. Each claim id can be associated to up to 3 plans and I want to show each plan and tally amounts in one record. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks for any ideas.  :)

Output result set needed:

```
claim_id    ac_name     plan_name_1   pending_tally1 plan_name_2     Pending_tally2 plan_name_3    pending_tally3
--------    -------     -----------   -------------- -----------     -------------- -----------    --------------
1234        abc cooks   delux_prime   22             prime_express   23             standard_prime 2
2341        zzz bakers  delpux_prime  22             standard_prime  2              NULL           NULL
3412        azb pasta's prime_express 23             NULL            NULL           NULL           NULL
```

SQL Server 2005 table to use for the above result set:

**company_claims**

```
claim_id    ac_name     
1234        abc cooks
2341        zzz bakers
3412        azb pasta's
```

**claim_plans**

```
claim_id    plan_id     plan_name
1234        101     delux_prime
1234        102     Prime_express
1234        103     standard_prime
2341        101     delux_prime
2341        103     standard_prime
3412        102     Prime_express
```

**Pending_amounts**

```
claim_id    plan_id     Pending_tally
1234        101     22
1234        102     23
1234        103     2
2341        101     22
2341        103     2
3412        102     23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that 3 is always the max amount of plans then some left joins will work fine:

```
select c.claim_id, c.ac_name, 
       cp1.plan_name as plan_name_1, pa1.pending_tally as pending_tally1,
       cp2.plan_name as plan_name_2, pa2.pending_tally as pending_tally2,
       cp3.plan_name as plan_name_3, pa3.pending_tally as pending_tally3,
from company_claims c
left join claim_plans cp1 on c.claim_id = cp1.claim_id and cp1.planid = 101
left join claim_plans cp2 on c.claim_id = cp2.claim_id and cp2.planid = 102
left join claim_plans cp3 on c.claim_id = cp3.claim_id and cp3.planid = 103
left join pending_amounts pa1 on cp1.claim_id = pa1.claimid and cp1.planid = pa1.plainid
left join pending_amounts pa2 on cp2.claim_id = pa2.claimid and cp2.planid = pa2.plainid
left join pending_amounts pa3 on cp3.claim_id = pa3.claimid and cp3.planid = pa3.plainid
```

Comment: Thanks Hogan, the available plan id's that can be allocated to a claim number into the thousands, but only three of them, so I don't think I'll be able to join on the plan id = 101 etc......1000+  I'm sorry i should have made that more clear.  :(

Comment: @Montwill This will be faster for just 3 all the time (even if those 3 change it is easy to join to a table that describes them -- I can show you that if you want) but if you need "dynamic" then a pivot is a better (but harder) choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would first join all your data so that you get the relevant columns: `claim_id, ac_name, plan_name, pending tally`.

Then I would add transform this to get plan name and plan tally on different rows, with a label tying them together.

Then it should be easy to pivot.

I would tie these together with common table expressions.

Here's the query:

```
with X as (
  select cc.*, cp.plan_name, pa.pending_tally,
    rank() over (partition by cc.claim_id order by plan_name) as r
  from company_claims cc
  join claim_plans cp on cp.claim_id = cc.claim_id
  join pending_amounts pa on pa.claim_id = cp.claim_id
    and pa.plan_id = cp.plan_id
), P as (
    select
      X.claim_id, 
      x.ac_name, 
      x.plan_name as value,
      'plan_name_' + cast(r as varchar(max)) as label
    from x
  union all 
    select
      X.claim_id, 
      x.ac_name, 
      cast(x.pending_tally as varchar(max)) as value,
      'pending_tally' + cast(r as varchar(max)) as label
    from x
)
select claim_id, ac_name, [plan_name_1], [pending_tally1],[plan_name_2], [pending_tally2],[plan_name_3], [pending_tally3]
from (select * from P) p
pivot (
  max(value)
  for label in ([plan_name_1], [pending_tally1],[plan_name_2], [pending_tally2],[plan_name_3], [pending_tally3])
) as pvt
order by pvt.claim_id, ac_name
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68f62/10

Comment: thanks jtsend, I'm sorry if I mis-understand your answer, but I'm trying to get the output with a sql script without having to move to excel to pivot table etc...

Comment: @Montwill I was talking about SQL's PIVOT, not Excel's PIVOT.